# Tkinter Treeview item background

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have (or at least tried) to read the documentation of the treeview for tkinter and I cannot find if you can change the background color of each row.  For example, I would like to have the background changed for every odd row to ease reading.

Is there a way to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878730/ttk-treeview-alternate-row-colors, though generally excessive control of the colors is considered bad - the colors should be managed by the selected theme.