# Python ttk - is it possible to show grid lines?

Tags: python, user-interface, ttk

I'm trying to use ttk.Treeview() for sortable tables. It would be helpful if I could show grid lines. I tried to use Style() for this but found nothing. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

header = ['col1', 'col2']
data = [('a', '4') ,('b', '1') ,('c', '2') ,('d', '3') ,('e', '5')]

root = Tk()

f1 = ttk.Frame(root)
f1.pack()
t1 = ttk.Treeview(f1, columns=header, show="headings")
t1.pack()

for col in header:
   t1.heading(col, text=col.title())
for item in data:
   t1.insert('', 'end', values=item, tags=('items',))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear as it is. Please share your code and elaborate more

Comment: I think the OP means add seperators between each item, in which case I can't find any information about that but you may consider [alternating the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878730/ttk-treeview-alternate-row-colors) to indicate the seperation.

Comment: yes, you're right, I'd like to add separators between the lines. Found a solution re alternating background, but I'd like to solve this in a less complex way. There's going to be large sets of data...

Comment: ... which later I'd like to sort, filter, mark, copy (and paste somewhere else)

Comment: @MartinM did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: no, didn't find a solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a grid lines inside of tkinter treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557281/creating-a-grid-lines-inside-of-tkinter-treeview)