# Creating a grid lines inside of tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I have one simple treeview made in tkinter. Is it possible to make a grid inside the tkinter treview, so that it looks more like a table?

I want to make it more "user-friendly", so visualization of the table/treeview can be better.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" Program ")                         
myApp.geometry("800x700")


tree = ttk.Treeview(myApp,height=25)
tree['show'] = 'headings'

sb = ttk.Scrollbar(myApp, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
sb.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="NS",pady=5)

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

tree["columns"]=("1","2","3")

tree.column("1", width=50)
tree.column("2", width=50)
tree.column("3", width=50)

tree.heading("1", text="Col 1")
tree.heading("2", text="Col 2")
tree.heading("3", text="Col 3")

item = tree.insert("", "end", values=("",))

tree.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the only option to make it more "user-friendly" is to create alternating row colors:

```
tree.insert("", "end", values=("a",),)
tree.insert("", "end", values=("b",), tag='gray')
tree.insert("", "end", values=("c",),)
tree.insert("", "end", values=("d",), tag='gray')
tree.tag_configure('gray', background='#cccccc')
```