# tkinter Treeview: Changing even and odd row colors in treeview by using tags and tag_configured wont work at all

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I've been having a hard time on finding solution on mine where the tags and tag.configured wont work to change my oddrow and evenrow background color to easily see the rows on the inventory list even i am copying the example code but still wont work for me. To further understand the problem, this is the the part of the code that we're having trouble with:

```
    for record in records:
        #print(sorted(str(record[0]), reverse=False))
        col_head.insert("", "end", text=record, values=(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5]), tags=('ODDROW'))
        col_head.tag_configure('ODDROW', background='gray')
```

and when executed. . .

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aMFh.png)

The Treeview in the inventory wont even show any gray background or other colors I try to input in the tag_configure, if you want to look on the whole program, here it is

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3
import os


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3
import os


def invent():

    def inventory_tab():

        invent_display = Tk()
        invent_display.geometry("1250x650")
        invent_display.configure(bg="gray")
        invent_display.title("Inventory Tab")

        #Name of the Retailer FRAME1
        title_box = Frame(invent_display, width=1000, height=100, pady=5, bd=10, background='light blue', relief="raise")
        title_box.grid(column=1, row=1)
        retailer_name = Label(title_box, text='retailer name', width=50, height=1, bd=2, font=("Calibri", 35), relief="sunken")
        retailer_name.grid(column=0,row=0, pady=5)

        #Date FRAME2
        dtformat = datetime.now()
        date_time_format = dtformat.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        date_and_time = Label(title_box, text=date_time_format, width=50, height=1, bd=2, font=("Calibri", 20), fg='green', relief="sunken")
        date_and_time.grid(column=0,row=1)

        # INVENTORY LIST FRAME3
        inventory_list = Frame(invent_display, width=500, height=500, bd=10, pady=10, relief="sunken")
        inventory_list.grid(column=1, row=2)

        # treeview Multiple Column
        col_head = ttk.Treeview(inventory_list,
                                column=("prod_id", "p_name", "p_brand", "initial_stock", "stock", "price" ),
                                show='headings')
        #scrollbar in the Column
        invent_scroll = Scrollbar(inventory_list, orient="vertical", command=col_head.yview)
        invent_scroll.grid(column=2,row=1, sticky=NS)
        col_head.configure(yscrollcommand=invent_scroll.set)

        #heading TItle
        col_head.heading("#1", text="Product ID")
        col_head.heading("#2", text="Product Name", anchor=W)#, command=inventory_sort)
        col_head.heading("#3", text="Product Brand")
        col_head.heading("#4", text="Initial Stock")
        col_head.heading("#5", text="Stock")
        col_head.heading("#6", text="Price")
        col_head.grid(column=1, row=1)

        # Input Values from Database
        # Create Database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Inventory_table.db')

        # Create cursor
        c = conn.cursor()

        # print
        c.execute("SELECT prod_id, p_name, p_brand, initial_stock, stock, price FROM inventory")
        records = c.fetchall()

        for record in records:
            #print(sorted(str(record[0]), reverse=False))
            col_head.insert("", "end", text=record, values=(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5]), tags=('ODDROW'))
            col_head.tag_configure('ODDROW', background='blue')



        # BUTTON ORGANIZE FRAME4
        button_organize = Frame(invent_display, width=1200, height=250, pady=5, bd=10, relief="raise")
        button_organize.grid(column=1, row=3)

        #Column1 add record FRAM4
        add_record_label = Label(button_organize, text='Add Record Tab', width=71, height=3, bg='pink')
        add_record_label.grid(column=1,row=0)
        add_rec_frame = Frame(button_organize, width=400, height=250, bd=2, pady=5, relief="raise")
        add_rec_frame.grid(column=1,row=1)

        #LABEL
        p_name_label = Label(add_rec_frame, text='Product Name:')
        p_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10, 0))
        p_brand_label = Label(add_rec_frame, text='Product Brand:')
        p_brand_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        initial_stock_label = Label(add_rec_frame, text='Initial Stock: ')
        initial_stock_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        stock_label = Label(add_rec_frame, text='Stock:')
        stock_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
        price_label = Label(add_rec_frame, text='Price:')
        price_label.grid(row=4, column=0)

        #ENTRY
        p_name = Entry(add_rec_frame, width=30)
        p_name.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        p_brand = Entry(add_rec_frame, width=30)
        p_brand.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)
        initial_stock = Entry(add_rec_frame, width=30)
        initial_stock.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20)
        stock = Entry(add_rec_frame, width=30)
        stock.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20)
        price = Entry(add_rec_frame, width=30)
        price.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

        #BUTTON
        add_btn = Button(add_rec_frame, text="Add record")#, command=add_record)
        add_btn.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=58)
        clear_btn = Button(add_rec_frame, text="Clear Entry")#, command=add_record)
        clear_btn.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=58)



        #Column2 edit/search/delete recordsFRAM4
        #Column3 inventory setting FRAM4
        invent_display.mainloop()

    # Insert Variable Here only used for Inventory Tab

    table_checker = os.listdir()

    if 'Inventory_table.db' in table_checker:
        # Create Database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Inventory_table.db')

        # Create cursor
        c = conn.cursor()

        inventory_tab()

    else:
        # Create Database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Inventory_table.db')

        # Create cursor
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE inventory (
                prod_id integer,
                p_name text,
                p_brand text,
                initial_stock integer,
                stock integer,
                price integer
                )""")
        inventory_tab()
invent()
```

i'm new to python by the way and recently learned about tkinter and some stuffs. So any help and suggestion are highly appreciated.

By the way, this code needs a db, the file is here if you're going to run the program[Inventory_table.db](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gCUuPI9wS7kizqOYb6htqUaStsHKFu2v)

Thanks in advance again for the help!

P.S. Im using Python 3.8 as my project interpreter with Pycharm's IDE

EDIT: the tkinter version i am using based on the tkinter.TclVersion is version 8.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ttk treeview: alternate row colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878730/ttk-treeview-alternate-row-colors)

Comment: Which version of tk are you using? There is a bug with row colors in tk 8.6.9: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/509cafafae

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 I actually saw this and it wont work, even tried to youtube but still  even i copy paste the code it wont work on mine

Comment: @j_4321 based on my pycharm, it says i have a version 8.6 from tkinter.TclVersion

Comment: Ok but you need to get the sub-sub version as well to know if it is the bug since it occurs only for version 8.6.9 but not 8.6.8 or 8.6.10.

Comment: @ULCOblivion a single `,` can also make a difference. Did you try using `tags = ('oddrow',)`

Comment: @j_4321 do you know how to get the sub version? and if any case do you know how to update tkinter to the version you suggesting? thanks for the help btw

Comment: @FrainBr33z3 i tried it just now at it still won't work.

            col_head.insert("", "end", text=record,
                            values=(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5]),
                            tags=('ODDROW', ))
            col_head.tag_configure('ODDROW', background='blue')

Comment: I know how to do it in Archlinux `pacman -Qi tk` or debian based linux distros `dpkg-query -W tk`. If you are using Windows, tk is shipped with the python version you installed so you can probably determine the tk version on python download page.

Comment: ok ok @j_4321 ill be checking that now. if in any case of downgrading or upgrading tk in windows, do you know how to update version of tk in windows?

Comment: I don't know but you might find something on tcl/tk website https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/

Comment: i now know that the current tkinter version is  8.6.9 using this command
import tkinter
x = tkinter.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')
print(x)

looks like i have to look for another way around to install the latest version. thanks for the assistance, ill update when i fixed the problem